# Updating an object inside an array in Firebase Firestore react JS

Tags: arrays, firebase, if-statement, syntax, jsx

I want to be able to update a string inside an array that is stored in Firestore.
Now, I went througn their docs, and there is no such method. what they do provide is arrayUnion (to add another element to the array) and arrayRemove (to remove an element from an array).

So I thoguht I call on arrayUnion to add the new content and then arrayRemove to remove the old one thus, in practice, updating it.

However, if I only use arrayUnion it works fine, if I use both, only arrayRemove works and the new elemnt is not added. any Ideas?

```
const updateField = async (e, id, obj) => {
    const taskDoc = doc(db, "Task", id);
if (e.target.id == "updateTodos") {
      const updatedTask = {
        Todos: arrayUnion(updatedTodo),
        Todos: arrayRemove(obj),
      };

      await updateDoc(taskDoc, updatedTask);
      setUpdateHadHappened(updateHasHappened + 1);
      exitEditMode();
    }
```

notice that writing:

```
        Todos: arrayUnion(updatedTodo), arrayRemove(obj),
```

or

```
        Todos: arrayUnion(updatedTodo); arrayRemove(obj);
```

does not work..

Answer (score 0):

ok, solved it! it's all about syntax my friends:

```
const updateField = async (e, id, obj) => {
    const taskDoc = doc(db, "Task", id);
if (e.target.id == "updateTodos") {
      const updatedTask = {
        Todos: arrayUnion(updatedTodo),
      };

      await updateDoc(taskDoc, updatedTask);

      const updatedTask2 = {
        Todos: arrayRemove(obj),
      };

      await updateDoc(taskDoc, updatedTask2);
      setUpdateHadHappened(updateHasHappened + 1);
      exitEditMode();
    }
```